# Translating "Choose Multiple" Checkbox Forms from Survey123 to ArcGIS Online Maps?

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer, arcgis-survey123

I have a request for a few ArcGIS Online forms that require possible multiple answers in certain situations. I did notice that this is can be done using Survey123 forms and checkboxes.

But when the same feature is being edited in an ArcGIS Online Map it does not show the checkboxes, it only shows a large textbox. I was curious if there is a workaround that allows you to be able to choose mutiple "answers" in arcGIS Online similar to how it looks in Survey123. There are some people that like using Survey123, but a majority of people prefer using Collector or the ArcGIS Online webmaps to enter the data. Here are a couple images to show what I am referring to.

Form in Survey123
[image]

Form when Seen in ArcGIS Online
[image]

Comment: You can do this by setting up domains on the database that holds that feature class.  Once you set the domains and publish the service,  the attribute will have drop down menus.

Comment: As far as I know, even if a domain list is defined for a multi-select question, it will not show as a drop-down in AGOL.  https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/filtered-select-multiple-choice-list-does-not/td-p/1087864

Answer (score 3):

By default, the response to a multiple-answer question in Survey123 is stored as a comma-separated list of the answers in one attribute field (column) of your layer. That's what you are seeing in the ArcGIS Online popup.

However, you can change this so that each option of your multiple-answer question is represented by a separate field, with YES/NO or 1/0 values. In your case, it could be fields like: pullbox17x30, pullbox24x30, and pullbox36x30.

If you want to use Survey123 to set this up, you can follow the instructions described here:
https://community.esri.com/groups/survey123/blog/2017/08/30/understanding-multiple-choice-questions-in-survey123-for-arcgis
in the section "Controlling how user selections are stored in ArcGIS"

Then the popup in ArcGIS Online would include a separate entry for each Pullbox size, where you would indicate Yes/No.